# Google Map freezing in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

when I integrate google map in flutter, the first once I launch the screen that contains google map widget it freezes my app.
    note I'm using tab view widget and google map is the third tab in my app.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class MapModlue extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => MapModlueState();
}

class MapModlueState extends State<MapModlue> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  double opacity = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        decoration:
            new BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 1.0)),
        child: Opacity(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            )));
  }

  // ignore: invalid_override

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    Timer _timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {
      // this timer to hide black screen that appear before map loading
      setState(() {
        mapController = controller;
        opacity = 1.0;
      });`enter code here`
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: May have been caused by a Windows Update.  In Internet Explorer see if this page works properly: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple

Comment: Did you try without passing `mapController = controller;` to `setState()`? This is notifying the framework that a state of the widget changed, which since you are doing it on `GoogleMapController` it could potentially lead to some sort of drawing loop. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Comment: I am facing the same problem in normal screen not Tabview. any update ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shared seems to loop on configuring `GoogleMapController` inside `setState()`. This causes the map to be rebuilt multiple times. You don't need to call `setState()` to configure `GoogleMapController`. It's also demonstrated on [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugin's [sample](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/main.dart).

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and while researching find out this solution and it works.
Just wrap the setState with if and put there "mounted" as condition:

```
if (mounted) {
        setState(() {}
   }
```